# Automated installation using preseeding from url failed (from within VirtualBox)

Tags: installation, virtualbox, preseed

I'm trying to do automated installation using preseeding from url, but it failed.

Basically, I'm following

Ubuntu Server Quick Install, No Questions Asked!
http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/03/ubuntu-server-quick-install-no.html

Using the Ubuntu 12.04 desktop ISO, and append the following options to the kernel command line (ESC, then F6 at the boot screen):

```
priority=critical locale=en_US url=http://goo.gl/PBKbX
```

The installation should proceed from start to finish, but mine failed at the first step resolving goo.gl.

what's wrong?

I also tried to add auto, as per
https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/preseed-using.html
ie., appending

```
priority=critical locale=en_US auto url=http://goo.gl/PBKbX
```

but still, can't resolve goo.gl

How can I fix it?

**PS. this is run from within VirtualBox.**

Comment: Have you tried it without using goo.gl to shorten the links?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the desktop ISO with **ISO Master** works for me.

1. Run ISO Master in the bottom pane.
2. Open the isolinux directory.
3. Edit the `txt.cfg` file.

   I added the following entry (changed the url though)

   ```
   default live
   label live
   menu label ^Autoinstall
   kernel /casper/vmlinuz
   append  url=http://goo.gl/PBKbX/live.seed automatic-ubiquity boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash noprompt auto=true --
   ```
4. Save the image and try it.

I assume setting the kernel options manually should work as well. Make sure you have set the VirtualBox network settings correctly (e.g useing NAT).

Comment: What are you linking to with goo.gl, this is confusing, and using link shortening services is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

Change the network adapter mode in virtualbox to 'Bridge' instead of NAT. Sometimes NAT doesn't get you proper networking access, and therefore your DNS lookup will fail.